# Emoji keyboard crashing

Tags: android, methods, crash

I'm a fairly new developer, so please go easy on me.

I'm making a chat app, and I'm planning on adding support for custom emojis, similar to how Discord manages custom emojis. However, my app is crashing once I tap on the emoji button. I want it to inflate my layout (emoji_keyboard_layout.xml) and view that in a LinearLayout in ChatActivity.

I've tried adding the view itself to the layout *(yeah that didn't work in my case, but if that is the only solution possible, then I will try it again)* and I've also tried modifying my onClick, modifying the actual method, but whatever I did, nothing would fix it.

My openEmojiKeyboard method:

```
private void openEmojiKeyboard(Boolean EMOJI_STATE, Boolean GIF_STATE)
{
    View emojiKey = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emoji_keyboard_layout, llEmojiKeyboard);

    llEmojiKeyboard.addView(emojiKey);
    llEmojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    hideKeyboard(etMessage);

    final LinearLayout llSelectContent = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llSelectContent);
    final LinearLayout llSelectToolbar = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llSelectToolbar);
    final LinearLayout llEmoji = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llEmoji);
    final LinearLayout llGif = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llGif);

    final LinearLayout llEmojiSelected = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llEmojiSelected);
    final LinearLayout llGifSelected = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.llGifSelected);

    final TextView tvEmptyContent = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyContent);
    final TextView tvEmptyContent1 = emojiKey.findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyContent1);

    if (EMOJI_STATE && !GIF_STATE) // The emoji keyboard is open, gif keyboard is closed
    {
        llEmojiSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llGifSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tvEmptyContent1.setText(R.string.add_emoji);
        tvEmptyContent.setText(R.string.empty_emoji_content);
    }
    else if (GIF_STATE && !EMOJI_STATE) // The gif keyboard is open, emoji keyboard is closed
    {
        llGifSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llEmojiSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tvEmptyContent1.setText(R.string.retry);
        tvEmptyContent.setText(R.string.empty_gif_content);
    }
}
```

My activity's onClick event:

```
case R.id.ivEmoji:
            openEmojiKeyboard(EMOJI_STATE, GIF_STATE);
            break;
```

**The emoji keyboard functionality is not ready yet, just preparing the layout**

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Crashing on lines `llEmojiKeyboard.addView(emojiKey);` and `openEmojiKeyboard(EMOJI_STATE, GIF_STATE);`

Comment: To help us pinpoint the issue, can you provide the logs of the crash from logcat? That should show exactly where the crash is occurring.

Comment: It's crashing on the lines llEmojiKeyboard.addView(emojiKey); and openEmojiKeyboard(EMOJI_STATE, GIF_STATE);

---------

Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Please edit your question above to include the stacktrace so others can see it when they read the question.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have indicated in the logs is telling you that the view (`emojiKey`) already has a parent (root) view. This is because you passed `llEmojiKeyboard` as a root view via the second argument in `LayoutInflater.inflate()`. Since this is already the root view, you don't need to call `.addView()` after inflating, or if the `.addView()` call is necessary, you can pass a boolean as a third argument to `.inflate()` to control whether the newly inflated view gets attached to the root `ViewGroup` ([here is the documentation for that version of the `.inflate()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))):

```
View emojiKey = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emoji_keyboard_layout, llEmojiKeyboard, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Also I'm really bad at this, *how do I add the view to my linear layout*

Comment: You're not really bad at this, you're running into a new issue you haven't seen before. There's a big difference. As for the linear layout, in keeping with Stack Overflow's question and answer format, go ahead and post a new question for that (helps makes sure others can find the right info when they search for an issue).

Comment: Thank you, I'll go post a new question.